# Users with same "quarter reputation" have different "top [ ]% this quarter" ranking

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, reputation-leagues

Midnight UTC just passed 45 minutes ago, and the "quarter reputation" & "total reputation" numbers in the leagues page have updated. However, it looks to me like my "top [ ]% this quarter" number is not consistent with other users with the same "quarter reputation".

In my profile, I am listed as "top 2% this quarter", although when I click on that link to view the leagues rankings, I find several users with the same "quarter reputation" (1263) or lower (1262, 1261) who are listed as "top 0.90% this quarter", "top 0.89% this quarter", and "top 0.91% this quarter".

If I have 1263 "quarter reputation" and those three have 1261-1263, why are they all tightly around "top 0.90%" and I'm at "top 2%"?

Comment: 3 hours after midnight UTC, no further updates.

Comment: I believe you, but I'd be better if there's a screenshot for that occurrence since I only see "top 0.47% this week" on your profile now. (I assume this is on [so] since that's the site you have more than 1k rep).

Comment: you're correct, that's what it says now. So I guess the answer is it just takes a few hours after UTC midnight to update the "top [ ] % this [ ]" stat. No need for a further answer on why it switched from 'this quarter' to 'this week', that's been explained well elswhere.

Answer (score 1):

Per the timeline of comments on my question, the answer here was that the "top [ ]% this [ ]" stat in my profile updated sometime after 3am UTC time and before 5am UTC time.

I had thought the update would have happened much closer to midnight UTC, when the leagues rankings page updated.

Comment: I assume doing the recalc on each user takes some time, dependng on when you did join it's more or less long after the league update for the batch to update your profile...